# Cleaning up docker-compose data volumes in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project based on Docker and docker-compose files which I would like to test via Jenkins.

We have a number of docker-compose files which we are using for testing, and all of those write to a `data` directory relative to the project root, e.g.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  simple:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-standalone
    ports:
     - "1005:1005"
    volumes:
     - ./data/simple/logs:/launcher/logs
     - ./data/simple/repository:/launcher/repository
```

The issue I've hit is that docker creates the data directory as root, and there is no way to clean it up from Jenkins. I am not allowed to use `sudo` from my Jenkins job, so that's not an option.

I need at least the logs directory available on the local filesystem for running some checks from the Jenkins job.

How can I make sure that the whole `data` directory holding the data volumes is deleted at the end of the build?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem and solved it by using `chmod` inside the container after it performed the functions I needed it to, then was able to delete the directories it created as the jenkins user. I'm sure there's a better solution, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to let docker manage the volumes by using named volumes in the compose files, e.g.:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  simple:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-standalone
    ports:
     - "1005:1005"
    volumes:
     - simple-logs:/launcher/logs
     - simple-repository:/launcher/repository
volumes:
    - simple-logs:
    - simple-repository:
```

The volumes are then stored by docker in a private area (`/var/lib/docker` in for me ). But most importantly, they can be managed via the `docker volume`. Docker-compose even offers a nice shorthand for deleting those volumes using `docker-compose down --volumes`. According to the documentation this argument removes the named volumes declared in the *volumes* section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes attached to containers.

My cleanup script can now simply invoke `docker-compose down --volumes`.